# Can a three wire Electrical conductivity sensor (Sensorex CS 150) be used directly with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, electronics

I am having an electrical conductivity sensor (Sensorex CS150 with three tinned wires Red, Black and white https://sensorex.com/product/sensorex-cs150-12-mm-graphite-contacting-conductivity-sensor/ ). I want to measure EC of nutrient soultion used in aquaponics. I have searched on internet for connection setup and everywhere sensor (with BNC connector) is connected to arduino via expansion board. Do I require this type of expansion board or can I directly connect sensor to analog pin of arduino.

Comment: unfortunately the product page doesn't state anything about what exactly each wire is for, nor how it would be connected. Can you link to the sites you found, where a connection to the Arduino is descriped?

Answer (score 2):

EC electrodes is an active sensor that requires an excitation voltage to be applied to get the result. When A DC voltage is apply to the two conductors, it caused iron to be flow from one conductor to another, causing polarisation and chemical reaction. Therefore you can't use it directly with Arduino.

To measure EC you need a Wien bridge oscillator which is used to generate an alternative current(AC) waveform for the excitation of the EC electrode. In order to avoid polarization, an alternative current (AC) typically ranging from 1kHz to 20kHz is used to provide the exitation of the electrode. The AC current is read and converted back to a DC voltage as the measurement result.

You also need a precision amplifier in order to get a meaningful measurement.

The EC value is also subject to temperature changes, so it may also requires to measure the temperature of the liquid and adjust the result for temperature compensation.

I have an [product review article](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/07/a-review-on-seeed-studio-ph-and-ec-sensor-kits-part-2/) where it describe how EC measurement works and what is required (both hardware and software) to measure EC, you might want to further read to understand more.

Other reference:

[Conductive of a solution - Andy Connelly](https://andyjconnelly.wordpress.com/2017/07/14/conductivity-of-a-solution/).

[Conductivity Measurement Theory Guide -](https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/library/guides/lab-analytical-instruments/Conductivity-Measurement-Theory-Guide.html) .

[One-chip conductivity meter monitors salt concentration - Michael Ahmon Electronics/Sept 15, 1977](https://www.e-tinkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/one-chip_conductivity_meter_by_Michael_Ahmon_Sept_1977_Electronics.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

[Product Manual](https://sensorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/CS150-Instructions.pdf)

Seem to be a simple conductivity measurement so applying a voltage direct from the Arduino via a suitable resistor and using an analog input to measure the voltage drop should work OK. You may need to experiment with the resistor value to get a good range of readings depending on the conductivity of the solution you are measuring